# IIS6 Classic ASP cannot server one sub folder

Tags: asp-classic, iis-6, windows-2003-webserver

I just setup a new server for a client to move their code from a hosted solution to a server in their office. New hardware running Windows 2003 Server with IIS 6. All the Service packs up to date. There are two separate websites running in IIS. The first is their corporate website. The second site is their web app.

The web app has one default.asp page on the root and then all the code is in subfolders (no subwebs). ALL the code runs except ONE FOLDER called "Reports". There is nothing special about this folder?

The error message is as follows:
Server Error in '/Reports' Application.
This type of page is not served.
Description: The type of page you have requested is not served because it has been explicitly forbidden.  The extension '.asp' may be incorrect.   Please review the URL below and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /reports/DoctorListingSearch.asp

I have checked the web extensions is set to allow ASP Classic. I have delted and recreated the web several times, I have added IUSR_ and NETWORK_SERVICE and even just given each full control with no success.

Again, ALL the other code and folders in this website work fine. Any ideas on what to do next? I have scoured the internet but have not found anything useful on how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed SQL Server 2008 Reporting Services? It creates a folder called "reports" by default if you install it on IIS. You could try changing the URL that SQL Reporting Services uses with the SQL Server Configuration Wizard.

Comment: Been stuck on this issue for a few hours this morning. Sure enough, issue was the ReportServer which doesn't show in IIS. Magic my friend!

Answer (score 0):

In IIS 6 I *think* you also need to give IWAM_ full or change permissions on that folder.